# How to configure NodePort on Digital Ocean Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I am new to Kubernetes. I have searched that you can use a `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` to expose services. I am trying to follow tutorials on https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/.

I am able to expose service with `LoadBalancer` but not `NodePort`. Here is the command I used.

```
kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type="NodePort" --port 8080
```

Comment: It is unusual to want to use NodePort with a cloud provider - that's more typical for on-premise. See https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0

Comment: However it is supported on gke and they have a good guide - https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_nodeport Maybe see if those steps work for digital ocean?

Comment: @RyanDawson Nah, I found out why. I thought `targetPort` and `port` was like port mapping in Docker. Actually the real expose port is another one that get auto assigned.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're specifically following ['Use a Service to Access an Application in a Cluster'](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/)

Just to note in an answer what you came to already in the comments, you don't set a `--port` parameter on the `expose` in that example and just on the `run`. You set the port that the Pod responds to in the `run` command but not the port exposed externally in `expose` - k8s will choose that for you automatically from the NodePort range and then tell you which one it chose. Then you find a public IP for a node in order to access.